# `this` and scope in Javascript callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I will show the code directly:

```
disable: function(e){
    that = this;
    var haha = this;
    $.post(url, function(){
        console.log(this);// (why ajax object here?
        console.log(that);// (I understand this one works
        console.log(haha);// ReferenceError 
    })
}
```

What I get confused here is:

1. Why `this` in callback does not refer to the outside one? I think `this` in callback follow the default binding role.
2. Why `haha` does not refer as `that` do? I think when `haha` is not found in local scope, it will go to outer scope.

I know using `that` is not a good way. That's why I tried `haha`, but it failed.
[image]

Comment: What is the "default binding role"?

Comment: `haha` should refer to the same object.... also there is a bug in the code as `that` is not local to the `disable` method, some other script could change its value

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/v1ejqxwd/1/

Comment: You can also use `bind`, eg `$.post(url, function() { console.log(this) }.bind(this))`

Comment: @Phil `$.post(url, (function() { console.log(this) }).bind(this))`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny err, yeah I forgot `url`. Brevity got the better of me but you don't need to wrap the function in parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is: Because you can rebind it willy-nilly in Javascript, and jQuery happens to for `jQuery.post()`, as [the documentation for `jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) states:

> The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the `context` option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if `context` is not specified, `this` is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

Generally: you should probably never rely on a Javascript library to **not** rebind `this`. If you need its value in a nested callback, just save it. Either in a different-named variable, or using [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
$(function() {
    var self = this;
    $.post("/echo/json/", (function() {
        console.log("self", self); // this will be the document itself
        console.log("this", this); // as will self
        console.log("self === this", self === this); // should output true
    }).bind(this));
});
```

Example on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/millimoose/Lx2oxobg/. For what it's worth, I **strongly** prefer using a separate variable for readability, because you can give it a descriptive name, and the fact that `this` isn't rebound, and that you've effectively reassigned one of the parameters of the callback, isn't hidden all the way **after** the block for which this holds true.

As for your question 2, I can't reproduce it, see my second fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/millimoose/zL352rzf/. As others have stated, you're probably not actually getting the `ReferenceError` from the `console.log()` itself, given your screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are trying to access those values from console... in that case `haha` will not work as it is local to the function, where as you have created `that` as a global variable(as there is no `var` used).

But that is a wrong pattern because some other script could modify the value of `that` before the ajax request is completed.

Comment: I put a break point in callback function and prints out those values. Why haha does not work in this way?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `context` option of `$.ajax()` to set `this` of `success` , `error` callbacks

```
disable: function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      context: this
      , type:"POST"
      , url:url 
      , success: function() {
          console.log(this);
        }
      , error: function() {
          console.log(this)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback function runs in a different its own scope hence this refers to it, not where it was defined. you can use bind or apply or call functions to bind it. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

so this refers to something else, but since that is declared in the scope that the function was declared in it still exists there.